# Dropwizard Resource testing, wrong http method maybe?

Tags: java, jax-rs, dropwizard

So, when writing tests for a dropwizard application(0.8.2 is the version used), the resource (It's called UserResource in this specific case) is already written, and while testing that resource, I get an error about a completely irrelevant method. So, here's the error message:

```
[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public bounswegroup3.model.User bounswegroup3.resource.UserResource.updateUser(bounswegroup3.model.AccessToken,bounswegroup3.model.User) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class bounswegroup3.resource.UserResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@6f815e7f]}, definitionMethod=public bounswegroup3.model.User bounswegroup3.resource.UserResource.updateUser(bounswegroup3.model.AccessToken,bounswegroup3.model.User), parameters=[Parameter [type=class bounswegroup3.model.AccessToken, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class bounswegroup3.model.User, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class bounswegroup3.model.User}, nameBindings=[]}']
```

I get the error when testing the getAllUsers endpoint. Here's the setup code for testing:

```
@ClassRule
public static final ResourceTestRule resources = ResourceTestRule.builder()
    .addResource(new UserResource(userDao, menuDao, mealDao, mailer))
    .build();
```

...

```
    ArrayList<User> res = resources.client().target("/user/").request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ArrayList.class);
```

And here's the bits of the resource I'm testing

```
@Path("/user")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class UserResource {
```

...

```
@GET
public List<User> getUsers() {
    return dao.getUsers();
}
```

...

```
@POST
@Path("/update")
public User updateUser(@Auth AccessToken token, @Valid User user) {
    if (token.getUserId() == user.getId()) {
        dao.updateUser(user);
    }

    return user;
}
```

So, it seems like the test sends a POST request and not a GET one, the resource than routes that to the update user path, and complains when it can't find a request body. Any idea on what causes the problem and/or a solution to that?

Comment: You need to register your auth provider I believe. The resource is instantiated as one, not partly. So when you try to execute your method, DW discovers that you didn't bind any auth provider for the post, so the valid is simply not valid (DW doesn't know which one you want to call, so it just throws an exception)

Comment: Yep, adding the auth provider did the trick (it took a while figuring out how to add that, though)